# Why does express.Router() return a function not an object?

Tags: node.js, express

I recently realized that what `express.Router()` return is a function but not an object. And `get` method is mounted on `router.__proto__`. What confused me is why not just use a single global object to stand for a router but a function? Thanks!

[image]